# Is Oracle's TextFieldDemo example catching the wrong Exception?

Tags: java, oracle, demo

I tried Oracle's TextFieldDemo.java example.  Initially I did not have file "content.txt" in the correct folder, and the Demo bombed with a StackTrace. Ugly. But the file read code does have try-catch for IOException:

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("content.txt");
try {
    textArea.read(new InputStreamReader(in), null);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

So, I changed 'e.printStackTrace()' to 'System.out.println("Cannot find file");' and still got the StackTrace.

So, I changed 'IOException' to 'Exception', and the program ended gracefully with my message.

Is Oracle's TFDemo catching the wrong exception?

Comment: Why not try e.toString(); intstead? In any way you should be looking for FileNotFoundException

Comment: I will try e.toString().  Thanks.  I did try e.getMessage() and got 'null'.

Comment: I also tried a catch block for FileNotFoundException, and got no hits.  As far as I can tell, no-one is throwing that Exception.

Comment: e.toString() returns 'java.lang.NullPointerException'.

Comment: so you likely don't have the content.txt file to begin with. Throw the try before the first line instead.

Comment: Good point and suggestion.  I moved the '= getClass()...' statement into the try block, and still 'catch (Exception)' is the only catch block that executes.